# Make CURAND generate different random numbers from a uniform distribution

Tags: random, cuda, seed

I am trying to use CURAND library to generate random numbers which are completely independent of each other from 0 to 100. Hence I am giving time as seed to each thread and specifying the "id = threadIdx.x + blockDim.x * blockIdx.x" as sequence and offset . 
Then after getting the random number as float, I multiply it by 100 and take its integer value.

Now, the problem I am facing is that its getting the same random number for the thread [0,0] and [0,1], no matter how many times I run the code which is 11. I am unable to understand what am I doing wrong. Please help.

I am pasting my code below:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include<curand_kernel.h>
#include "util/cuPrintf.cu"
#include<time.h>

#define NE WA*HA //Total number of random numbers 
#define WA 2   // Matrix A width
#define HA 2   // Matrix A height
#define SAMPLE 100 //Sample number
#define BLOCK_SIZE 2 //Block size

__global__ void setup_kernel ( curandState * state, unsigned long seed )
{
int id = threadIdx.x  + blockIdx.x + blockDim.x;
curand_init ( seed, id , id, &state[id] );
}

__global__ void generate( curandState* globalState, float* randomMatrix )
{
int ind = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
if(ind < NE){
    curandState localState = globalState[ind];
    float stopId = curand_uniform(&localState) * SAMPLE;
    cuPrintf("Float random value is : %f",stopId);
    int stop = stopId ;
    cuPrintf("Random number %d\n",stop);
    for(int i = 0; i < SAMPLE; i++){
            if(i == stop){
                    float random = curand_normal( &localState );
                    cuPrintf("Random Value %f\t",random);
                    randomMatrix[ind] = random;
                    break;
            }
    }
    globalState[ind] = localState;
}
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Program main
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

// 1. allocate host memory for matrix A
unsigned int size_A = WA * HA;
unsigned int mem_size_A = sizeof(float) * size_A;
float* h_A = (float* ) malloc(mem_size_A);
time_t t;

// 2. allocate device memory
float* d_A;
cudaMalloc((void**) &d_A, mem_size_A);

// 3. create random states    
curandState* devStates;
cudaMalloc ( &devStates, size_A*sizeof( curandState ) );

// 4. setup seeds
int n_blocks = size_A/BLOCK_SIZE;
time(&t);
printf("\nTime is : %u\n",(unsigned long) t);
setup_kernel <<< n_blocks, BLOCK_SIZE >>> ( devStates, (unsigned long) t );
// 4. generate random numbers
cudaPrintfInit();
generate <<< n_blocks, BLOCK_SIZE >>> ( devStates,d_A );
cudaPrintfDisplay(stdout, true);
cudaPrintfEnd();
// 5. copy result from device to host
cudaMemcpy(h_A, d_A, mem_size_A, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);


// 6. print out the results
printf("\n\nMatrix A (Results)\n");
for(int i = 0; i < size_A; i++)
{
   printf("%f ", h_A[i]);
   if(((i + 1) % WA) == 0)
      printf("\n");
}
printf("\n");

// 7. clean up memory
free(h_A);
cudaFree(d_A);

}
```

Output that I get is :

Time is : 1347857063
**[0, 0]: Float random value is : 11.675105[0, 0]: Random number 11**
[0, 0]: Random Value 0.358356   **[0, 1]: Float random value is : 11.675105[0, 1]: Random number 11**
[0, 1]: Random Value 0.358356   [1, 0]: Float random value is : 63.840496[1, 0]: Random number 63
[1, 0]: Random Value 0.696459   [1, 1]: Float random value is : 44.712799[1, 1]: Random number 44
[1, 1]: Random Value 0.735049

Comment: With CUDA 5.0 I am unable to reproduce this problem. I ran your code and it created four completely different random values.  Can you try upgrading to CUDA 5.0 RC?  Note I also compiled with `-arch=sm_20` so I could use `printf` since I don't have `cuPrintf` around anymore.

Comment: I am using CUDA 4.2... Can you please run the code with this version and check as I am unable to find where to download CUDA 5.0 RC on Nvidia.

Comment: [Here it is](http://developer.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-pre-production). Please try it.  BTW, Google is very good at finding these things. :)

Comment: Ok ... I am using CUDA 4.2 right now...I got the CUDA 5.0 RC... I will try with CUDA 5.0 and let you know the results

Comment: Yeah I missed the link in the first search I think :). Got it now ....

Comment: Ok...I used the CUDA 5.0 now but still I get the same output with [0,0] and [0,1] threads giving 11 as random number. Please help.

Comment: I am giving the link for cuPrintf files. Please use them and check the output. http://code.google.com/p/stanford-cs193g-sp2010/source/browse/trunk/tutorials/util

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few things wrong here, I'm addressing the first ones here to get you started:

**General points**

- Please check the return values of all CUDA API calls, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/cuda/info) for more info.
- Please run cuda-memcheck to check for obvious things like out-of-bounds accesses.

**Specific points**

- When allocating space for the RNG state, you should have space for one state per thread (not one per matrix element as you have now).
- Your thread ID calculation in setup_kernel() is wrong, should be `threadIdx.x  + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x` (* instead of +).
- You use the thread ID as the sequence number as well as the offset, you should just set the offset to zero as described in the cuRAND manual:

> For the highest quality parallel pseudorandom number generation, each
>   experiment should be assigned a unique seed. Within an experiment,
>   each thread of computation should be assigned a unique sequence
>   number.

Finally you're running two threads per block, that's incredibly inefficient. Check out the CUDA C Programming Guide, in the "maximize utilization" section for more information, but you should be looking to launch a multiple of 32 threads per block (e.g. 128, 256) and a large number of blocks (e.g. tens of thousands). If you're problem is small then consider running multiple problems at once (either batched in a single kernel launch or as kernels in different streams to get concurrent execution).

Comment: I did not get allocating space for 1 state per thread as according to my understanding each thread is generating one random number which is corresponding to one element in my matrix. Anyways you caught the right typo error... The id calculation in setup_kernel was the problem. So thanks a lot Tom :)